# Como proteger o site de Clickjacking

Tags: php, html, html5, segurança, vulnerabilidade

Olá, fiz um varredura no meu site e encontrei que ele está vulnerável a ataques do tipo clickjacking, vi que uma solução seria implementar o cabeçalho-frame-opções x HTTP, minha duvida é como implementar isso? Seria uma simples tag html inserida no header? Qual seria essa tag?

Comment: Alguém que possa me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Adicione isso ao PHP:

```
header('X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN');
```

Particulamente eu adicionei na `header.php`, que é incluída em todas as outras páginas.

Fonte: [codeengineered](https://codeengineered.com/blog/2013/secure-site-clickjacking-x-frame-options/)

Answer (score 1):

Um site tem um protocolo, host e porta i.e, `http://exemplo.com/` é `(http, exemplo.com, 80)`. `https://exemplo.com/` é um site diferente `(https, exemplo.com, 443)`.

Para evitar esse acesso, você pode configurar o  `x-frame-option` para **SAMEORIGIN**. Isso significa que somente outras paginas da mesma origem pode acessar, no nosso caso de exemplo `http://exemplo.com`.

---

No caso do PHP podemos definir o cabeçalho antes que o conteúdo da página seja enviado. Isso pode ser feito usando a função `header`.

```
<?php
header('X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN');
?>
```